# There was an error running the selected code generator: No Parameterless constructor defined for type

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

[image: There was an error running the selected code generator: No Parameterless constructor defined for type]

I've created the Model and DbContext but when I'm about to generate a Controller using EF core an error shows.

**LocationDbContext**

```
using Intranet.Models.CorpComm;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Intranet.Data.CorpComm
{
    public class LocationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public LocationDbContext(DbContextOptions<LocationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the code for your dbcontext class here! thanks

Comment: We don't check out code bases and dig through random splatterings of projects on github (unless of course you are paying), please read [ask]

Comment: The link doesn't even work

Comment: _"No Parameterless constructor defined for type LocationDbContext"_, you say. Hmm.. what can this means?.. Oh! I get it! there is no parameterless constructor defined for `LocationDbContext`! That was hard!

Comment: @vasily.sib sorry I'm just starting .net core, I don't have an idea what that is.

Comment: @JoseBalerosJr, it ok to be newbie, but you need to be more curious. For example, if you don't know what is `Parameterless constructor` - just ask it (on google, for example). There you can find that parameterless constructor is a constructor without parameters. If you don't know what a `constructor` is - you need to learn a lot of things first and .net Core MVC is just to hard for you. Start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/getting-started/) then.

Comment: Hey @JoseBalerosJr did you ever get this working?

I ran into the same issue.  I did add the parameter constructor and it moved to next problem.   

I looked back in history and this was working without a parameter constructor at one point.   Curious if you ran into same thing.

btw - other commenters on this post.  You guys all should be ashamed with your responses to Jose.

Answer (score 1):

This is a parameterless constructor.

```
public LocationDbContext() { }
```

You should add it like this:

```
using Intranet.Models.CorpComm;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Intranet.Data.CorpComm
{
    public class LocationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public LocationDbContext(DbContextOptions<LocationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public LocationDbContext() { } // here
        public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and was unable to solve by my own, landed here while trying to search for a solution.
I solved my using a work around
I added an OnConfiguring method to set the connection string and removed the parametrized constructor.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
 optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("<connection string");
}
```

Once the code generator was executed successfully, I then revered back to the parametrized constructor and everything worked as expected.